# How to reset application data in Windows 8/WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-8, storage

I have a user setting, which asks the user if he wants to reset the app.
When the user hits Reset, I need to clear all the data in the local folder? My local folders have many sub folders. I have been searching for a remove function which removes the contents of local folder without any hassle? `DeleteAsync`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have used `DeleteAsync` to remove the folder and its contents.

```
private async Task<bool> DeleteFolder() 
    {
       var folderlist = await m_localFolder.GetFoldersAsync();
       foreach (StorageFolder folder in folderlist)
       {
           await folder.DeleteAsync(StorageDeleteOption.PermanentDelete);
       }           

       return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the helper class suggested [here](http://codepaste.net/gtu5mq).

It is very useful for managing LocalFolder and LocalSettings.